# extraArgs outputting to console log with NaN

Tags: javascript, nan

I'm following a tutorial and the code below is outputting Extra Arg:  NaN.  I'm not sure why that's the case and I even tried extraArgs[i].toString().

```js
let myFunc = function (name, weather,...extraArgs) {
    console.log("Hello " + name + ".");
    console.log("It is " + weather + " today");
    for (let i=0; i < extraArgs.length; i++) {
        console.log("Extra Arg: ", + extraArgs[i]);
    }
};

myFunc("Adam", "sunny","one", "two", "three");
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just remove the + sign. And you should be good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have an extra comma when you log to the console, so it thinks that the second part of the argument, extraArgs[i] is a number because the plus sign in front of it makes it think so. You could remove either the comma or the plus sign and the problem should go away.